# doubly linked list java remove from back

Tags: java

Every time I run my Doubly Linked List, all of the methods work except when I remove from the back of the list. I had a List that was 4, 3, 9. I removed from front (which took away the 4). Then, I called this method that should've only removed the 9. Instead, when I call for the DL list, it returns null (which removes the 3 as well). PLEASE help.

```
    public Object removeLast() {
    Object result = null;

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        result = lastNode.getData();
        lastNode = lastNode.getPreviousNode();

        if (lastNode == null)
            firstNode = null;
        else
            lastNode.setNextNode(null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the rest of the code (which extends an interface; the generated code isn't necessary for the problem, so we haven't filled it in.. i.e. stuff after Node doesn't matter) THE CORRECT CODE:

```
    public class DList implements DoubleEndedListInterface {

    public Node lastNode;
    public Node firstNode; // reference to first node
    public int numberOfEntries;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + firstNode;

    }

    public Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition) {
        assert !isEmpty() && (1 <= givenPosition)
                && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries);
        Node currentNode = firstNode;

        // traverse the list to locate the desired node
        for (int counter = 1; counter < givenPosition; counter++)
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();

        assert currentNode != null;

        return currentNode;
    } // end getNodeAt

    public void addFirst(Object newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);

        if (firstNode == null)
        {
            firstNode = newNode;
            lastNode = newNode;
            numberOfEntries++;
        }
        else 
        {
            newNode.setNextNode(firstNode);
            firstNode.setPreviousNode(newNode);
            firstNode = newNode;
            numberOfEntries++;
        } // end if
    } // end add


    public void addLast(Object newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);

        if (firstNode == null)
        {
            firstNode = newNode;
            //lastNode = newNode;
            numberOfEntries++;
        }
        else 
        {
            lastNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            lastNode = newNode;
            numberOfEntries++;
        } // end if
    } // end add

    @Override
    public Object removeFirst() {
        Object result =  firstNode.getData();
        firstNode = firstNode.getNextNode();
        if (numberOfEntries == 1)
            lastNode = null; // solitary entry was removed

        numberOfEntries--;

        return result; // return removed entry, or
                        // null if operation fails
    } // end remove

    @Override
    public Object removeLast() {
        Object result = null;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            result = lastNode.getData();
            lastNode = lastNode.getPreviousNode();

            if (lastNode == null)
                firstNode = null;
            else
                lastNode.setNextNode(null);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFirst() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return firstNode.getData();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getLast() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lastNode.getData();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void moveToEnd() {
        Object temp = (Object) remove(1);
        add(numberOfEntries + 1, temp);

    }

    public class Node {
        public Object data; // entry in bag
        public Node next; // link to next node
        public Node previous;

        public Node(Object dataPortion) {
            this(dataPortion, null, null);
        } // end constructor

        public Node(Object dataPortion, Node nextNode, Node previousNode) {
            data = dataPortion;
            next = nextNode;
            previous = previousNode;
        } // end constructor

        public Object getData() {
            return data;
        } // end getData

        public void setData(Object newData) {
            data = newData;
        } // end setData

        public Node getNextNode() {
            return next;
        } // end getNextNode

        public Node getPreviousNode() {
            return previous;
        }

        public void setPreviousNode(Node previous) {
            this.previous = previous;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node nextNode) {
            next = nextNode;
        } // end setNextNode

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node [data=" + data + ", next=" + next + "]";
        }

    } // end Node

    @Override
    public void add(Object newEntry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(int newPosition, Object newEntry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(int givenPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean replace(int givenPosition, Object newEntry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getEntry(int givenPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object anEntry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean result;

        if (numberOfEntries == 0) // or getLength() == 0
        {
            assert firstNode == null;
            result = true;
        } else {
            assert firstNode != null;
            result = false;
        } // end if

        return result;
    } // end isEmpty

    @Override
    public void swap(int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTooBig() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reduceArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void makeRoom(int newPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeGap(int givenPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeObject(Object anObject) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object anObject) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void append(ListInterface bList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `removeLast` in the first place rather than as the second call?  Also, there isn't really enough code here to properly help... would you mind posting the rest of your code to make it easier to debug?

Comment: While I'm not entirely sure why your code is working the way it is, providing more code could help us identify the errors in your implementation. In addition, @abiessu might be onto something, and you should tell us what happens when you call it first instead of last.

Comment: My money's on you not setting `lastNode` properly. More code would help us figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: when I comment out the remove first so remove Last is first, it still returns null when I print the list. Adding the entire code in a moment.

Comment: I agree with @kviiri , it looks like you are not setting `lastNode` to anything. Also, in your `add` method you are declaring a local variable called `lastNode`, is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry all, I uploaded the wrong code. :x please let me know if this is still the problem here or not.

Answer (score 0):

`removeLast` makes perfectly sense, though maybe there is a missing `--numberOfEntries`.
The rest of the code I did not read, as it is a bit too much.

But `add` is weird: it seems to use a local variable `lastNode`  doing nothing with some field `lastNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see:

`addFirst` looks ok, it appears as though this method should operate correctly.

`addLast` does not appear to be correct.  In particular, if a node is added to an empty list via `addLast` the `lastNode` member variable will not have a valid value.

Then both `removeFirst` and `removeLast` need help, especially with the handling of the `numberOfEntries` member and doing checks for an empty list.

For the "list begins empty" condition, you should also set the "next" and "previous" pointers to null so that there is no chance of stray data interfering.